# Save Files that containing Files Name with Different Characters using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to upload files using php. Uploading is working.
But i have a file which contain file name (not content) with different language. (ex. japaneese characters). 
But after i upload that file to server; file name showing with different characters.
How do i upload Same file name to the Server.

Comment: What string functions are you running the filename through?

Comment: What charset is the upload page in? What charset is the OS/filesystem using?

Comment: Never use a user supplied file name for anything except displaying it, make up your own filename (that you know is safe) and store the file with the name; then store the user supplied filename in the database somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've got a character encoding problem.  You'll have to make sure your HTML form and your PHP configuration use the same character set.  UTF-8 is the preferred one since it contains characters from almost all widely spoken languages.  Your Form tag should include an attribute like so:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" ...>
```

Also, check that your `php.ini` file specifies the default character set:

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

If you can't control what's in your `php.ini`, you could try putting it in your `.htaccess` file (assuming a typical Apache server.)  Like so:

```
php_value default_charset UTF-8
```

For good measure, you can also add a Content-Type meta tag into your HTML header section specifying UTF-8:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

If you're storing any filenames in a database, you'll have to make sure that it too is using UTF-8.